# What's the difference between undefined in Haskell and null in Java?

Tags: java, haskell, types, null, option-type

Both are terms whose type is the intersection of all types (uninhabited). Both can be passed around in code without failing until one attempts to evaluate them. The only difference I can see is that in Java, there is a loophole which allows `null` to be evaluated for exactly one operation, which is reference equality comparison (`==`)--whereas in Haskell `undefined` can't be evaluated at all without throwing an exception. Is this the only difference?

### Edit

What I'm really trying to get at with this question is, why was including `null` in Java such an apparently poor decision, and how does Haskell escape it? It seems to me that the real problem is that you can do something *useful* with `null`, namely you can check it for *nullness*. Because you are allowed to do this, it has become standard convention to pass around null values in code and have them indicate "no result" instead of "there is a logical error in this program". Whereas in Haskell, there's no way to check if a term evaluates to bottom without evaluating it and the program exploding, so it could never be used in such a way to indicate "no result". Instead, one is forced to use something like `Maybe`.

Sorry if it seems like I'm playing fast and loose with the term "evaluate"... I'm trying to draw an analogy here and having trouble phrasing it precisely. I guess that's a sign that the analogy is imprecise.

Comment: Let's see: one's in Haskell, and one's in Java?

Comment: @Matt that's just syntax, I mean semantically

Comment: A closer equivalent to Java's `null` is Haskell's `Nothing`. Essentially, every object reference in Java is like a Haskell `Maybe` value. `Integer foo = new Integer(5)` is like `let foo = Just 5`, while `Integer foo = null` is like `let foo = Nothing`.

Comment: @Chuck that's one way of looking at it, but I don't think it's as direct as just saying `null` behaves a lot like `undefined` except you can do an operation to check if a term evaluates to `null`

Comment: @Chuck: It ends up being a bit of both, really. Since object references can always be null, by that analogy everything in Java is prefixed with a `fromJust` which produces an error if used on `Nothing`. So, in theory it's closer to `Nothing` but in practice the semantics end up looking more like `undefined`.

Comment: @ILMTitan yes, it's evaluated using the loophole operator `==`... the only way you're allowed to (safely) evaluate null is to check it for nullness.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> What's the difference between undefined in Haskell and null in Java?

Ok, let's back up a little.

"undefined" in Haskell is an example of a "bottom" value (denoted ⊥). Such a value represents any undefined, stuck or partial state in the program.

Many different forms of bottom exist: non-terminating loops, exceptions, pattern match failures -- basically any state in the program that is undefined in some sense. The value `undefined :: a` is a canonical example of a value that puts the program in an undefined state.

`undefined` itself isn't particularly special -- its not wired in -- and you can implement Haskell's `undefined` using any bottom-yielding expression. E.g. this is a valid implementation of `undefined`:

```
 > undefined = undefined
```

Or exiting immediately (the old Gofer compiler used this definition):

```
 > undefined | False = undefined
```

The primary property of bottom is that if an expression evaluates to bottom, your entire program will evaluate to bottom: the program is in an undefined state.

Why would you want such a value? Well, in a lazy language, you can often manipulate structures or functions that store bottom values, without the program being itself bottom.

E.g. a list of infinite loops is perfectly cromulent:

```
 > let xs = [ let f = f in f 
            , let g n = g (n+1) in g 0
            ]
 > :t xs
 xs :: [t]
 > length xs
 2
```

I just can't do much with the elements of the list:

```
 > head xs
 ^CInterrupted.
```

This manipulation of infinite stuff is part of why Haskell's so fun and expressive. A result of laziness is Haskell pays particularly close attention to `bottom` values.

However, clearly, the concept of bottom applies equally well to Java, or any (non-total) language. In Java, there are many expressions that yield "bottom" values:

- comparing a reference against null (though note, not `null` itself, which is well-defined);
- division by zero;
- out-of-bounds exceptions;
- an infinite loop, etc.

You just don't have the ability to substitute one bottom for another very easily, and the Java compiler doesn't do a lot to reason about bottom values. However, such values are there.

In summary,

- dereferencing a `null` value in Java is one specific expression that yields a bottom value in Java;
- the `undefined` value in Haskell is a generic bottom-yielding expression that can be used anywhere a bottom value is required in Haskell.

That's how they're similar.

**Postscript**

As to the question of `null` itself: why it is considered bad form?

- Firstly, Java's `null` is essentially equivalent to **adding an implicit `Maybe a` to every type `a` in Haskell**.
- Dereferencing `null` is equivalent to pattern matching for only the `Just` case: `f (Just a) = ... a ...`

So when the value passed in is `Nothing` (in Haskell), or `null` (in Java), your program reaches an undefined state. This is bad: your program crashes.

So, by adding `null` to *every* type, you've just made it far easier to create `bottom` values by accident -- the types no longer help you. Your language is no longer helping you prevent that particular kind of error, and that's bad.

Of course, other bottom values are still there: exceptions (like `undefined`) , or infinite loops. Adding a new possible failure mode to every function -- dereferencing `null` -- just makes it easier to write programs that crash.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point; it's not `null` itself that's the bottom value in java, it's a *dereferencing* of `null`.

Comment: I agree that adding `null` to every type is bad -- the type system does not help you catch `NullPointerException`s. But isn't allowing every value to be explicitly `undefined` the same problem? In a language like Haskell, the identity `x * 0 = 0` no longer holds because the value `x` could be undefined. Even though it has type `int`!

Comment: @ben The difference is that in Haskell once you have undefined you cannot change it to something non-bottom. This is why you avoid undefined any time your code works correctly. In Java, null is the default and having x = null is perfectly correct. It's just the dereference that's incorrect. But you can reassign x to some non-null value. So the "UndefinedPointerException" in Haskell can only happen after some other error, whereas in Java NullPointerExceptions are the original sources of failure.

Comment: *Every* programming language allows bottom as a value everywhere. Other programming languages just don't give it a special name, that's all. (E.g., if you wrote a C program, you can have a function that's declared to return `int`, but actually loops forever and never returns anything. *That's undefined!*)

Comment: I've gotten some understanding from this answer, so, some degree of undefined values will be present in your program no matter the language, simply due to mathematical constraints.

 But I don't follow why Haskell lets things such as let x = x in x be legal expressions at compile time, other programming languages don't allow this sort of circular definition. What is the rationale for this in Haskell?

Comment: @orm The reason for allowing `let x = x in x` is because you can actually do very useful things with recursively defined values. One example is the fibonacci sequence: `let fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) in fibs` generates (quite efficiently I should note) the infinite fibonacci sequence. Another is pascal's triangle: `let pasc = [1] : fmap (\x -> zipWith (+) (0 : x) (x ++ [0])) pasc in pasc`. I also use recursively defined data to efficiently generate primes, although that involves several mutually dependent functions so I can't easily paste it in here.

Comment: as for me Haskell often breaks traditional CS terminology: "leak" which is not leak :) "Undefined" in all standards means "can be any" - depends on architecture, memory layout, etc. "undefined" in Haskell is absolutely defined state/behavior: it raises exception and applications is aborting (when is evaluating) :)

Comment: if to be more strict: evaluating of undefined = dereferencing of null

Answer (score 7):

Your description isn't quite correct. You're saying `null` can't be evaluated. However since java is an eager language, this would mean that `f(null)` would throw an NPE no matter what the definition of `f` is (because method arguments are always evaluated before the method runs).

The only reason that you can pass around `undefined` in haskell without getting an exception is that haskell is lazy and does not evaluate arguments unless needed.

One further difference between undefined and null is that `undefined` is a simple value defined in the standard library. If it weren't defined in the standard library you could define it yourself (by writing `myUndefined = error "My Undefined` for example).

In Java `null` is a keyword. If there were no `null` keyword, you wouldn't be able to define it (doing the equivalent of the haskell definition, i.e. `Object myNull = throw(new Exception())`, wouldn't work because the expression would be evaluated right there).

Comment: Java is not completely strict. It behaves lazily, for example, when shortcutting boolean expressions. I think it would be just as accurate to say that `null` is a lazily evaluated expression in Java, and it's only evaluated when you say `null.something`. Therefore we can compare it somewhat directly to `undefined` in Haskell.

Comment: @pelotom: It would not be just as accurate to say that. For example, you could not write `if (foo != null)` if null weren't evaluated by that point (and by inference `foo` wouldn't have been evaluated either, since `foo` could be null!).

Comment: @pelotom: Yes, `&&` and `||` are non-strict. Method-application however is strict. So if any expression is given as an argument to a method, then the expression is evaluated before the method's body. You can't say "the expression will be evaluated first, *unless* the expression evaluates to null" - there would be no way of knowing whether an expression evaluates to null without evaluating.

Comment: @Chuck that's the loophole I mentioned... it allows evaluating `null` for reference equality, but nothing else

Comment: @pelotom: Except JLS Section 15.7 does not have any such loophole.

Comment: @ILMTitan all of Java has this loophole. If you could not "check if something was null" in Java, the `null` keyword would be completely useless, and no one would use it as a token to indicate failure. There would be no "billion dollar mistake". People would be forced to invent a Maybe type and document the partiality of their functions in the type.

Comment: @pelotom: Haskell doesn't document partiality in the type either! Sure, Java doesn't really have much in the way of a static type system, but that's irrelevant to the meaning of `null`.

Comment: @camccann `Maybe` documents partiality, if the function is expected to be partial in normal use cases

Comment: @pelotom: No matter how hard you wish it to be true, the JLS says otherwise. If you can't accept the Java Language Specification as the specification of the java language, we have no common priors on which to base a rational discussion.

Comment: @pelotom: Right, and that's the difference: In Haskell you're expected to be explicit about possibly returning a non-value, in Java you aren't. It's a matter of culture and syntactic convenience, not the language itself, as such. You could litter Haskell code with `error` if you wanted, nothing would stop you (other than, perhaps, the crushing disapproval of every other Haskell programmer on the planet).