# The concept of Bottom in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, semantics, denotational-semantics

[Bottom in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom) described here is said to be any computation that have errors, is unterminated, or involves infinite loop, is of any type... is this specific to Haskell? We know in Lattice theory, there is also a notion of `Bottom` there.....and shouldn't Bottom be defined based on what's the order defined?

Comment: I wonder if this may pertain to your question: http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/12/hussling-haskell-types-into-hasse-diagrams/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962939/whats-the-difference-between-undefined-in-haskell-and-null-in-java

Comment: Nice! I have been wondering the `null` and `Object` in Java too!

Comment: I suggest Wikipedia's explanation, It's different from null/void or something looks similar.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Indeed there is an order of *definedness*, where bottom is the least defined value. Have a look at [this page about denotational semantics in Haskell](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) for a more thorough explanation.

Here is a lattice for the values of `Maybe Bool` taken from the wiki page. It shows that `Just True` is more defined than `Just ⊥` which is more defined than `⊥`.

[image]

Comment: Is `Just bottom` really the same definedness as `Nothing`? They do both have one layer of "definedness", but `Nothing` is a solid finish, while `Just bottom` is not.

Comment: @Dan They are not comparable because they are not in the same chain.  All you can say is that they are both above bottom.

Comment: @Dan, for some applications `Just bottom` is a solid finish too (`isJust` is one example).

Comment: This (type of) graphic is what gave me my first glimpse into domain theory.  Thanks for using it!

Comment: I particularly like how this graphic makes it clear why ⊥ is "Bottom".

Comment: @JohnL Here's why: `(_|_)`